# Rails 5, rendering the same view in a consecutive action doesn't refresh the browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering

Quick question, I've been trying for the last couple hours to discern what is causing the following behavior but it's just beyond my grasp.
I have this two actions on my 'UsersController':

```
def new
     @user = User.new
end

def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        flash[:success] = 'Wellcome, %s! You have successfully 
registered.' % [@user.name]
        format.html { redirect_to login_path }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        flash.now[:error] = 'Hmm... There seems to be some errors.'
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
end
```

end

Basically, we render a clean 'new' view, try to register a new user, and if the creation of a user fails, the application should flash a message for the current action (the create action), and render the 'new' view, updating the previous one with the flash information and the errors of the @user variable.

The problem is that, although the server processes the response just fine, the browser does not update the page, never re-renders the page, it keeps the stale 'new' view. I've looked the response with chrome's web tools and it bears the updated view, but for some reason the browser just won't render it.

I think it has something to do with caching, but really I'm out of my element here. If instead of rendering I just redirect to the new action, the flash works fine (removing the .now(), that is), but this way I lose the @user, which I would like to keep with it's full functionality.

Any ideas why this behaves like this, or at least how to solve it?

Comment: What happens if you keep the render, but remove the .now from the flash.now[:error]?  It seems that if you say flash now it will keep the page and update the flash message.  Maybe put the flash after the render

Comment: Mm, no, that doesn't work. The .now just narrows the lifespan of the flash data to the current request, removing it just makes it a regular flash.

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect_to the new action, when the user submits, it will still post to the create action and the `user_params` would still take effect. Simplying rendering `:new` on the already new page will not perform a fresh request/response. To initiate a fresh request you will have to use `redirect_to`.

Comment: Hmm, I'm following your line of thought. I know that redirecting instead of just rendering will initiate a new request, which will refresh the page, but what I don't understand is why the response given to the POST request directly (not a re-direction to the New action, hence a new request) wont render. This is specially weird given that Rails by default generates controllers with this exact same logic (minus the flashes), and the form errors show just fine.

Comment: What response exactly are you trying to render? It gives the request to the POST /users when you click the submit button. However since it didn't save it has nothing to render, and since you specified :new  it will just render the same new template.

Comment: Yes, it should render the same template, but updated, since now @user and flash[:error] both have data, and the view should reflect that. The weird part is that in the response to the POST request, I can see the updated view, but the browser does not render it for some reason.
So, to your question, I'm trying to render the response to the POST request.